# designing and planning a module

Tags: database-design, magento-1.7

I am at the planning stage of creating a new module for magento. This will be my first magento project, while I don't want it to get to complicated, I would like to try and stick to best practices, which leads me to this question.

The module I will be creating is a newsletter facility with various options which the user can edit. The project will meet the following criteria:

- allow a user to sign up for a newsletter
- to sign up you do not have to be a member of the site
- allows for various preferences to be automatically set
- allows for set preferences to be edited by the user
- recognises the country that user is in on sign up

My first thought was to create the module without taking into account any of the existing modules and add two tables to store user details and preferences. I have decided that this  won't be the best idea and assume that it could be better to utilise the newsletter module?

Would using raw sql be acceptable to add the preference options? obviously doing that I would have to:

- add a couple of columns to the users to table to link the preferences and user
- add a column to identify if there a member or just a newsletter subscriber
- add a table for user preferences

This leads me to question if its bad practice to play with the core tables (I assume it is)?

My main question is:

- What can I research/leverage in Magento to complete this first project, without it becoming to complicated?

Answer (score 0):

As you are adding columns it won't affect any functionality. Functionality are affected when there is some alteration of tables.

I think the best practice here would be
1) Add you specifics columns
2) Override the newAction from newsletter module
3) Change the phtml accordingly
4) Also the model functions

Hope everything works fine

Comment: with regards to database columns would I lose those changes on an upgrade?

Comment: No you wont lose the changes on upgrade.

Magento only upgrades core folder. So, you would have a local module that extends core module. There you can also use database upgrades. So, there wont be any changes on upgrades...

Comment: If you want more details on install and upgrade scripts check this
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-6-magento-setup-resources

Please ask if you face more issues. Thanks..